# Lucene condition AND in QueryBuilder

Tags: hibernate, search, lucene, hibernate-search, query-builder

Personal I have a problem in a query, want to put the AND clause in a term, however I am not getting and tried searching with no success.

Follow the example and return the query (I'm using to test Luke conditions upon my indece and the result are different)

```
    builder.bool()  
    .should(builder  
            .bool()  
            .should(builder.keyword()  
                    .onFields("campo01", "campo02", "campo03")  
                    .matching(query).createQuery())  
            .should(builder.keyword().wildcard().onField("campo01")  
                    .matching("*" + query + "*").createQuery())  
            .should(builder.keyword().wildcard().onField("campo02")  
                    .matching("*" + query + "*").createQuery())  
            .should(builder.keyword().wildcard().onField("campo03")  
                    .matching("*" + query + "*").createQuery()).createQuery())  
    .must(builder.keyword().onField("campo04").matching(0).createQuery())  
    .createQuery();
```

This code generates the following query lucene:

```
(((campo01:teste campo02:test campo03:teste) campo01:*teste* campo02*teste* campo03:*teste*) +campo04:0)
```

However this query is returning a result larger than expected. Conducting tests with Luke realized that Must was not ideal, needing to be the AND in place.

```
    (((campo01:teste campo02:test campo03:teste) campo01:*teste* campo02*teste* campo03:*teste*) AND campo04:0)
```

Thus the result is correct, however I could not make the build query to create this result.

Can anyone help or have any questions remained. What I really want is to put an AND condition in a particular field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea with using the 'must' and 'should' clauses.  You can construct a query that creates, effectively, a logical AND using them.  You're missing one thing.
The structure of an AND, such as:

```
query1 AND query2
```

Would be:

```
+query1 +query2
```

You're example misses the '+', or Must clause, on the first query, so while the second is required, the first isn't, though it influences the results weight.

So, specifically, what you want is

```
builder.bool()  
.must(builder  
        .bool()  
        .should(builder.keyword()  
                .onFields("campo01", "campo02", "campo03")  
                .matching(query).createQuery())  
        .should(builder.keyword().wildcard().onField("campo01")  
                .matching("*" + query + "*").createQuery())  
        .should(builder.keyword().wildcard().onField("campo02")  
                .matching("*" + query + "*").createQuery())  
        .should(builder.keyword().wildcard().onField("campo03")  
                .matching("*" + query + "*").createQuery()).createQuery())  
.must(builder.keyword().onField("campo04").matching(0).createQuery())  
.createQuery();
```

Or...

```
(+((campo01:teste campo02:test campo03:teste) campo01:*teste* campo02*teste* campo03:*teste*) +campo04:0)
```